Oracle SQL Need to identify distinct PK values where a grouped set contains a specified value in a column
There are several questions that are close to this, but I haven't found that they address my situation. I have the following table, SUBSCRIPTIONS, that identifies individual amenities in a subscriber's subscription:



User Id
Category
Rank
Method
Start Date
End Date
Amenity




A001
A
B
C
01-JUN-23
01-JUN-24
A1


A001
A
B
C
01-JUN-23
01-JUN-24
A2


A002
A
B
C
15-OCT-23
15-OCT-24
A1


A002
A
B
C
15-OCT-23
15-OCT-24
A2


A002
A
B
C
15-OCT-23
15-OCT-24
A3


A003
D
E
F
11-NOV-23
11-NOV-24
A1



User Id is the subscriber. The combination of Category, Rank, and Method are the way the subscriber signed up for their subscription. The start date is when the subscription starts. The end date is when the subscription ends. Amenity is the individual amenity.
Unfortunately, the subscription isn't identified by a solitary serial number/ID. An individual user's subscription is the combination of User Id, Category, Rank, Method, Start Date, and End Date.
I need to identify distinct User Ids where their subscription of Category = A, Rank = B, and Method = C does not include amenity A3.
So from the above table, I would need to identify that User Id A001 had a subscription combination of A, B, and C but did not have amenity 'A3'. User Id A003 did not have 'A3' but their subscription combination was D, E, and F.
select DISTINCT User Id
from SUBSCRIPTIONS
where Category = 'A'
and Rank = 'B'
and Method = 'C'
and Amenity <> 'A3'

This is clearly wrong because it's just removing rows that have amenity 'A3'. I researched GROUPING SETS and GROUP BY CUBE, but I'm not aggregating data here so grouping expressions aren't working.
What is the proper approach for creating sets and checking for a specified value in each set?

The desired result based on the sample data above would be...



User Id




A001



...as that is the only User Id with amenity A3 on a combination of A, B, and C.

Sample table data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Use GROUP BY and conditional aggregation in a HAVING clause:
SELECT User_Id
FROM   SUBSCRIPTIONS
WHERE  Category = 'A'
AND    Rank = 'B'
AND    Method = 'C'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE Amenity WHEN 'A3' THEN 1 END) = 0;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (User_Id, Category, Rank, Method, Start_Date, End_Date, Amenity) AS
SELECT 'A001', 'A', 'B', 'C', DATE '2023-06-01', DATE '2024-06-01', 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A001', 'A', 'B', 'C', DATE '2023-06-01', DATE '2024-06-01', 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002', 'A', 'B', 'C', DATE '2023-10-15', DATE '2024-10-15', 'A1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002', 'A', 'B', 'C', DATE '2023-10-15', DATE '2024-10-15', 'A2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A002', 'A', 'B', 'C', DATE '2023-10-15', DATE '2024-10-15', 'A3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A003', 'D', 'E', 'F', DATE '2023-11-11', DATE '2024-11-11', 'A1' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



USER_ID




A001



fiddle


identify distinct User Ids where their subscription of Category = A, Rank = B, and Method = C does not include amenity A3.

Break the problem down:

Step 1: Get the set of UserIds with Category = A, Rank = B, and Method = C, regardless of Amenity = A3.
Step 2: Get the set of UserIds with Category = A, Rank = B, and Method = C, and with Amenity = A3.
Step 3: Subtract the result of Step 2 from Step 1.

...and it's now a simple set-operations problem.

Like so:
WITH step1 AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        s.UserId
    FROM
        subscriptions AS s
    WHERE
        s.Category = 'A' AND
        s.Rank     = 'B' AND
        s.Method   = 'C'
),
step2 AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        s.UserId
    FROM
        subscriptions AS s
    WHERE
        s.Category = 'A' AND
        s.Rank     = 'B' AND
        s.Method   = 'C' AND
        s.Amenity  = 'A3'
)
SELECT UserId FROM step1
EXCEPT
SELECT UserId FROM step2;



Here's a working demo on DB-Fiddle (though I'm using MSSQL, not Oracle, because DB-Fiddle's Oracle server seems broken right now (it just stalls when I try to run CREATE TABLE)).
https://dbfiddle.uk/hqt1-Mym
Screenshot proof:


This works, as I confirmed om db-fiddle. However, my problem is that EXCEPT was introduced in 18, but my company is on 11g. Still a helpful approach though.

@WayneEastwood ...didn't 11g come out in 2007? ...looks like it was EOL'd with end-of-support in 2015-2018 - dare I ask how you're running an unsupported version? ...and I thought companies using Oracle invariably get roped-in to upgrading anyway?
